# How to get timespan between two dates in C

Tags: c

I have two dates and I'm wondering how to check if their difference is at least 2 months or greater.

Currently I'm converting both dates to seconds since Jan 1900 and then checking the difference in seconds and comparing it to the # of seconds in a month. Does C have a better built in function that gives timespans?

My date format: MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: **Define "month".** What's the difference between 01/31/2011 and 03/31/2011 (59 days)? And between 01/31/2012 and 03/31/2012 (60 days)? And between 06/30/2012 and 08/31/2012 (62 days)?

Comment: That's why I'm asking. My current implementation can have an error of a couple days when I just look at months as 2.6 million secs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C has [difftime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/difftime/) which basically does what you are doing.  There are many more powerfully date libraries you can use.

Comment: I'm using difftime (and struct tm) currently and it works to get the number of seconds between two dates. I'm looking more for a way to have the system decide if the two dates are 2 months apart or not.
I guess there's really no way to do that since any given month can't be defined in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into Ctime header. These 2 should do it for you:

1. [struct tm](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/tm/)
2. [difftime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/difftime/)